# How can I format a `Debug` value directly into a utf-16 string?

Tags: rust, utf-16

Suppose I have value of a type that implements `Debug` and I want to encode the result of formatting the value in utf-16. One way to do this would be to use `format!` and then convert the `str` to utf-16:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User {
    name: String,
    some_ids: [u8; 16],
    // more fields, etc. Quite a few of them, actually
}

pub fn display_to_u16(user: &User) -> Vec<u16> {
    let asutf8 = format!("{user:#?}");
    asutf8.encode_utf16().collect()
}
```

But it seems wasteful to not directly write the result as a utf-16 string - or more precisely a vector of utf-16 codepoints. Is there any way to directly format a value as a utf-16 string?

---

Note: The real requirements is to work with an abstract `dyn Debug` type as part of an impl of [`tracing_subscriber::field::Visit::record_debug`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/field/trait.Visit.html#tymethod.record_debug). The `User` type should serve as an example only. It is not feasible to "simply" implement a different serialization scheme. Working with the `Debug` trait is an integral part of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The conversion overhead should be pretty minimal unless this inside a really hot spot of your code.

Comment: @tadman It's a short-lived allocation of a few kB at each `tracing` event and span entry/exit. So it's not that bad, but I'd wanted to ask how to dodge the extra clutter just in case, avoiding it would definitely be appreciated. And some future ping on this question might just remind me to change it if it's possible then.

Comment: UTF-8 to UTF-16 is just a bit of byte swapping, so it shouldn't be too bad. I think Rust is pretty committed to having UTF-8 internally, though, so I wouldn't expect to be able to write directly to UTF-16 without conversion. Is UTF-16 output strictly necessary? It tends to be a lot bigger, which for high volumes of tracing output can be a problem.

Comment: @tadman yes to UTF-16. The output eventually ends up in JS land (context being a wasm app), where strings are encoded as UTF-16. I'd like to do this conversion on the rust side, cause going through [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) instead would involve additional `ffi` calls that are even more costly (and do a similar conversion under the hood anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format!()` macro always returns a `String`. However, the [`write!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) macro is the generic version that accepts anything that implements `std::fmt::Write` (or `std::io::Write`). So if there's a type that implements one of those and encodes to UTF16 on-the-fly, then that'd be your best bet.

I took a quick look and didn't find a 3rd-party crate that provides this, but it's easy enough to implement yourself:

```
use std::fmt::{Error, Write};

struct Utf16Writer(Vec<u16>);

impl Write for Utf16Writer {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(self.0.extend(s.encode_utf16()))
    }
    
    fn write_char(&mut self, c: char) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(self.0.extend(c.encode_utf16(&mut [0; 2]).iter()))
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
use std::fmt::{Debug, Write};

pub fn display_to_u16(user: &User) -> Vec<u16> {
    let mut writer = Utf16Writer(Vec::new());
    write!(writer, "{user:#?}").unwrap();
    writer.0
}
```

You can assess the performance yourself, but I'm skeptical that this will make it faster (though it may use less memory overall). Intermediate calls may need to encode the relevant data into UTF8 (if they aren't already) in order to pass it as a `str` so you're not really saving any encoding steps.

Comment: It does save a few allocations, so this version is really appreciated!